# Why should the name of The Scottish play never be said?

Tags: blackadder

In Season 3, Episode 4 of the television series [Blackadder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackadder), [Sense and Senility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense_and_Senility), Why should the name of the Scottish play never be said? What about the time when the Scottish play is to be performed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 'Scottish Play' nearly always refers to Shakespeare's Macbeth.  For some reason there is a superstition about the play, and theatre people never refer to it by name for fear of bad luck, but only referer to it as 'the scottish play'.

You can read about the superstition on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scottish_play).

Comment: It's also referenced in various pop culture arena's, I can think of episodes of both Friends(? - I think) and Castle where I've heard it mentioned.